# How to add link parameters to the links that get redirected from a certain site (bit.ly)?

Tags: .htaccess, url, drupal, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm receiving visitors through the short links I created on bit.ly to my site.

So for example when somebody goes to `bit.ly/wtrguide` they come to `waytorussia.net`

What I want is that in an example like that my own script on my site automatically adds some parameters such as `?referer=bitly&source=book` to the `waytorussia.net` URL *only* when the visitors come through a `bit.ly` link.

Is it possible to do something like this – to automatically add URL parameters depending on the source?

Can I do it through `.htaccess` and how? Or there's another way to do that?

Thank you!

PS the site runs on Drupal, if that matters.

Comment: You should really add those params in the bitly link itself. Doing it with `.htaccess` will cause a second redirect, which slows things down, and *could* be bad for SEO. I'd recommend just doing it with bitly.

Answer (score 0):

I second the prior comment you've received:

> You should really add those params in the bitly link itself. Doing it with .htaccess will cause a second redirect, which slows things down, and could be bad for SEO. I'd recommend just doing it with bitly. – Mike Rockett Apr 7 at 4:47

However, if you still want to do this, you can probably do it like this with [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and some [PCRE](http://ports.su/devel/pcre) [regular expressions](http://mdoc.su/n/pcrepattern.3):

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://catalogue.example.com/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  !referer=catalogue
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?referer=catalogue    [R]
```

However, the problem with the above is that the HTTP/1.1 spec (both the old revision as well as the updated RFC of the same protocol) doesn't appear to define a scenario at stake.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2 (**301 Moved Permanently**)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.36 (**Referer**)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2 (**Referer**)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2 (**301 Moved Permanently**)

> If the target URI was obtained from a source that does not have its
> own URI (e.g., input from the user keyboard, or an entry within the
> user's bookmarks/favorites), the user agent MUST either exclude the
> Referer field or send it with a value of "about:blank".

Unfortunately, nothing is mentioned about following HTTP 30x redirects when the `Referer` field is empty — no suggestion is made that the `Referer` be set to the prior URL location upon such a condition.

Generally with HTTP redirects, the value of the `Referer` HTTP header field doesn't change upon receiving a new `Location` header through a 301/302/30x HTTP redirects, so, unfortunately, the code above won't work for bit.ly, and there is basically no way to detect that the user originated from such a link other than creating special links within the bit.ly service itself.

Comment: BTW, more details of why Twitter's `t.co` URL elongation service is different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239168/why-twitters-t-co-shows-up-in-referer-but-no-other-url-shorteners-ever-do/38239169#38239169