# Why Twitter's t.co shows up in Referer, but no URL shorteners ever do?

Tags: http, url-rewriting, url-routing, redirect, http-referer

I've noticed a whole bunch of `Referer` links like `t.co/oPQO7Xdz` in my `access_log` files, but no other URL shorteners ever show up.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL shorteners never show up because [HTTP `301 Moved Permanently` et al](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2) redirects in HTTP are not designed to influence the [`Referer` HTTP Request Header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2) (apparently, not even if the header is blank, potentially due to the fact that it'll cause inconsistency in behaviour otherwise).

However, Twitter does not issue [`301 Moved Permanently`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c#ngx_http_error_301_page) redirects with its `t.co` service if it sees what it deems is a popular desktop or mobile `User-Agent`.  As the redirect is thus done outside of the HTTP stack, the `Referer` field in the subsequent brand-new HTTP Request would then be composed to include the prior HTML page that was responsible for the redirection, causing a `t.co` entry to appear in `access_log`.

```
% curl -v -A"iPhone;" t.co/oPQO7Xdz
* About to connect() to t.co port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 104.244.42.5...
* connected
* Connected to t.co (104.244.42.5) port 80 (#0)
> GET /oPQO7Xdz HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: iPhone;
> Host: t.co
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< cache-control: private,max-age=300
< content-length: 258
< content-security-policy: referrer always;
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< date: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 05:24:16 GMT
< expires: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 05:29:16 GMT
< server: tsa_o
< set-cookie: muc=1f43e292-e319-4818-ba81-f12d16e5b629; Expires=Tue, 19 Jun 2018 05:24:16 UTC; Domain=t.co
< x-connection-hash: 0dc5a2a6a7e83ac2d7fb207eb0cedf84
< x-response-time: 115
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
<
* Connection #0 to host t.co left intact
<head><meta name="referrer" content="always"><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://mdoc.su/n/curl"></noscript><title>http://mdoc.su/n/curl</title></head><script>window.opener = null; location.replace("http:\/\/mdoc.su\/n\/curl")</script>* Closing connection #0
```

Compare this to what were to occur otherwise (and which is the only way that most other URL shorteners redirect, which would preserve whichever `Referer` appears when the HTTP request first hits the HTTP stack of the browser):

```
% curl -v t.co/oPQO7Xdz
* About to connect() to t.co port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 104.244.42.69...
* connected
* Connected to t.co (104.244.42.69) port 80 (#0)
> GET /oPQO7Xdz HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: t.co
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< cache-control: private,max-age=300
< content-length: 0
< date: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 05:24:40 GMT
< expires: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 05:29:40 GMT
< location: http://mdoc.su/n/curl
< server: tsa_o
< set-cookie: muc=2c727b50-311f-4043-9861-9f703996a8a8; Expires=Tue, 19 Jun 2018 05:24:40 UTC; Domain=t.co
< x-connection-hash: 5583cc49ddbcefe8fac9ba392ca868fd
< x-response-time: 103
<
* Connection #0 to host t.co left intact
* Closing connection #0
```